# Why is there an undefined in my array after my function is called?

Tags: javascript

My task is to create an empty array, then add a function and when that function is called, it creates a new record object and pushes it into the empty array.

I created the function and tried to push three parameters into the function and it does take; however, the array comes back with three indexes instead of the 2 I listed. Why are they undefined?

```js
let collection = [];

const addToCollection = (title, artist, year) => {
  collection.push({
    title,
    artist,
    year
  });
  return collection;

}

addToCollection('tewt', 'dsfdsf', 2000);
addToCollection('tewt', 'dsfdsf', 2000);

console.log(addToCollection());
```

Is there a better way to write the code so there is no undefined in the collection array?

Comment: because you called `addToCollection()` without any parameter.

Comment: u mistake with `console.log(addToCollection());` change to `console.log(collection)`

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `addToCollection()` without supplying a `title`, `year` or `artist` when you call `console.log(addToCollection())`.

You want to log `collection` itself, not invoke the method which adds to it:

```js
let collection = [];

const addToCollection = (title, artist, year) => {
  collection.push({
    title,
    artist,
    year
  });
  return collection;

}

addToCollection('tewt', 'dsfdsf', 2000);
addToCollection('tewt', 'dsfdsf', 2000);

console.log(collection);
```